# Does positive 0=negative 0?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Determine whether the series converge, converge absolutely or diverge for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{1+a^n}$$I've done most of the homework, the only interval missing is (-1,0). If $a_n$ doesn't convert to 0, the series diverges or oscilates. I put b=|a| and get:

For even $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{b^n}{b^n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{1+\frac1{b^n}}=\dfrac1{1+\infty}=\dfrac1\infty$. 

For odd $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{b^n}{b^n-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{1-\frac1{b^n}}=\dfrac1{1-\infty}=-\dfrac1\infty$.

I dimly remembered the teacher talking about negative zeros and this seemed to be possible appearance of a positive and a negative zero. If those two limits are non-equal, the series oscilates and my homework is done.

Comment: For $-1\lt a\lt 0$, the series converges absolutely (and hence converges). This can be done by Comparison, noting that the bottom cannot become very small.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But comparison cannot be used on series with negative terms. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've split my answer into three parts, referring to three different things:

---

**1.** Since $|a|<1$ you have $a^n \to 0$, so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{a^n}{1 + a^n} = \dfrac{0}{1 + 0} = 0$$
There was no need to divide top and bottom by $a^n$ (or $b^n$ or whatever).

---

**2.** Certainly $+0=-0$; the only time when signed zeroes come into it is when you're taking, say, the limit as $x$ tends towards zero. For instance,
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{x}{|x|} = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x}{|x|} = -1$$
This refers not to the *value* of $0$, but to the *direction* from which $x$ approaches it. It's purely notational.

---

**3.** To determine convergence (or non-convergence) of your series, you need to do more than the above: from $\dfrac{a^n}{1+a^n} \to 0$ you can't deduce that the sum converges.

Comment: OMG, I didn't realize that. Since i began studying university math, I feel like my IQ dropped at least 20 points. Nevermind, I'm going to try and use some convergence tests on that...